# Angular2 component ngDoCheck is endlessly executed

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular2-docheck, ag-grid-ng2

I have a simple angular2 component that contains only an [ag-grid](https://ag-grid.com) component with some data bind to it.

My component implement the DoCheck and the ngDoCheck method is implement in the component.

```
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck 
{
    ngDoCheck() {
        console.log('do check..');
    }
}
```

I have realized that the ngDoCheck function is always running endlessly.

Any explanation about this issue.

Comment: Is this happening on all browsers?  It's only an issue for me on safari

Answer (score 3):

> This hook is called with enormous frequency — after every change detection cycle no matter where the change occurred.

Is a really dirty cycle, in fact even angular itself is suggesting to use more proper way to implement custom checks.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Wouldn't it still be firing constantly even if we didn't use this hook.   Is there a way of finding out what is changing endlessly?

Comment: well, do check runs every time the change detection run, this answer gives some hint to how check what is triggering the change detection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661242/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-what-is-triggering-change-detection-in-angular-2 , alternatively in some cases might be useful control the change detection manually by change the change detection strategy in that component ( and its children ) by setting 
@component({changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush}) and then control it manually with ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Possible cause makes it run infinitely is that you might have used ChangeDetectorRef in any of your components and you might not have unsubscribed subscription variables.

Answer (score 1):

In my case ngAfterViewChecked was called endlessly because of sentry.js which do monkey patching of console.log which triggers Change Detection.
I pulled off half of my hair till noticed that code below causes loop because of sentry.

```
ngAfterViewChecked () {

    console.log('Rendered');

}
```

Comment: @Kamil Just don't call console.log in ngDoCheck and some ather lifecycle hooks