# Is there any way to find out what is triggering change detection in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I recently released a new component and it seems to be triggering change detection multiple times a second:

```
  // some debugging code
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('DO_CHECK', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  }
```

Results:

[image]

I've yet to figure out what is triggering this.

Am I reading this output correctly? Change detection is being triggered multiple times a second?

Is there any good method for figuring out what is triggering change detection in an Angular 2 application?

Comment: What about setting a breakpoint in `ndDoCheck` and look up the stack trace where it comes from?

Comment: Pardon me if I come off as ignorant but, how do you find the breakpoint in the compiled code?

Comment: If you use Angular CLI, it uses webpack under the hood and creates source maps that allow you to debug typescript even though the browser runs JS. In Chrome dev panel go to Sources, find webpack on the left, expand it and then expand the folder . (dot). The TypeScript sources are there and you can set a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot @YakovFain

Comment: My answer from another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134894/1678151

Answer (score 1):

The [Angular DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh) provide a profiler that will list all change detection events and will show the source for each event.