# How to display Angular9 change detection process in browser?

Tags: angular

I have a complex component with many @Input() and async process. I want to optimize the component, thus intend to **analyze Angular4 change detection cycle** upon my component.

May I know how to **identify** if the Angular4 change detection system is being **triggered**, and the DOM is being **re-rendered**?

Probably, using `console.log(...)`?

Typically, I hope for something like (in browser console):

```
Change-detection running... no changes... 1
Change-detection running... no changes... 2
Change-detection running... no changes... 3
Change-detection running... no changes... 4
Change-detection running... changed
No DOM rendering
Change-detection running... no changes... 5
Change-detection running... no changes... 6
Change-detection running... changed
DOM re-rendered
Change-detection running... no changes... 7
Change-detection running... no changes... 8
```

How do I achieve this? Or how do you guy optimize the Angular4 performance? Any other approaches?

Comment: There's an interface onChanges which gets called when any input property of component changes.By this, you can keep track of any changes if occurs in your component (https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Answer (score 6):

i wanted to do the same but there is no lifecycle hook which can do that, so i did a hack, may be that will help you as well.

on any tag in the html template invoke a function and log on console when the function is executed.  Whenever the change detection will be executed, the template will get re-evaluated resulting in the function invocation.  That worked pretty well for me to analyze what's going

```
.html
<div>{{doNothing()}}</div>

.ts
doNothing() {
  console.log('template evaluated');
}
```

Comment: How did this work out? Was it useful. Maybe use a service and track global counts?

Comment: for me it was useful and did the job, all i wanted to know was how the push strategy along with other functions calls is working for my components and with this way i could figure out how many its evaluating the html template.
we can have a service with global counts but i really didn't have any need to do so and console logs were good enough.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I may try this with some kind of global service that counts changes to make sure nothing is going too crazy - especially as I'm introducing more animation and that may trigger more detection events that would expose things I've 'got away with'. But I should probably wait for Angular 7 in case they changed or added new things that will make this easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a ngFor in your template you can add trackBy. This will get called every time change detection triggers (https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation) and you can log out a statement. You can then set a breakpoint on the function and look at stack trace to see where change events are originating.

I stumbled across this method while trying to debug an issue that would crash the browser due to change detection getting constantly triggered.

template

```
<div *ngFor="let things of things; trackBy: trackThings"></div>
```

component

```
trackThings(index, thing) {
 console.log(index, question)
 return thing ? index : undefined;
}
```

Track by also improves performance: https://medium.com/@ramy_ali/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878

Answer (score 1):

The [Angular DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh) provide a profiler that lists all change detection events, shows the source for each event and also allows you to see which component has been checked during each CD cycle. Just make sure to select the "flame graph" and tick the "Show only change detection" checkbox. The components marked blue have been checked.

[image]